# Capitalization of "the" beginning a proper noun

Tags: capitalization, proper-nouns

When should "the" be capitalized when it begins a proper noun?

There are some proper nouns that seem to have their leading "the" included as part of their name/title. For example, *The Real Ghostbusters*. But there are others, such as *the Greenhill School* that seem like they could go either way (as in, *Greenhill School* could also be acceptable, so "the" is not part of the proper noun). What's the rule?

Comment: If you don't capitalize "the" with Greenhill School then you shouldn't capitalize "school" either. Or else you would just say Greenhill School.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proper noun capitalisation: “The Union” or “the Union”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/473804/proper-noun-capitalisation-the-union-or-the-union) ...  ... 'When capitalising a proper noun that has a “the” prefix, should the “the” be capitalised?' (which question already has an answer here: Capitalizing “the” when mid-sentence in a company name?)

Answer (score 0):

Just ask yourself what is part of the actual name.